# How to change the Date Format in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to change the date format of a datepicker control to display as shown below.

Äpr,23 - 2010

Any suggestions how to go about this ?

Comment: Have you tried to set your datepicker format as `MMM','dd - yyyy`? Or have you tried _anything_?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='MMM, dd - yyyy', 
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
```